# How to generate CSV formatted data from python?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

After running a python program, I obtain a list of numeric data. How can I format the data in CSV?
Goal:
I hope to format it so that I can reuse the CSV-formatted data in Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reminder. sorry I should delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your list of numeric data is stored in a variable - `numericList`

```
import csv
myFile = open(csvFile, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(myFile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerow(numericList)
```

*wb* indicates that the file is opened for **w**riting in **b**inary mode.

The `csvFile` should contain your list in csv format.

**Note:** If each element in the `numericList` list ***is a list*** in itself, `writer.writerows(numericList)` might be a better option than `writer.writeRow(numericList)`. This is because `writeRows` breaks up each element in list into columns if the elements are lists in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

for a simple case you can just as easily write it directly..

```
 f=open('test.csv','w')
 for p in data : f.write('%g,%g\n'%tuple(p))
 f.close()
```

where data here is an `nx2` array.